# Unresolved external symbol in libgcrypt.lib

Tags: visual-c++, libvlc, unresolved-external, libgcrypt

What I have to do if i found Unresolved external symbol in .lib(library) file. If I found unresolved external symbol in .c or .cpp I can fix it. But when i found Unresolved external symbol in .lib(library) file how can i solve this?

In my case i found a linker error like this:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___mingw_vfprintf referenced in function _fprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-global.o)
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___mingw_vfprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-misc.o)
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strerror D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(ecc.o)
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strerror referenced in function __gcry_strerror  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-global.o)
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strerror D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-misc.o)
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strerror D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(md.o)
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strerror D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-fips.o)
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gpg_strsource referenced in function __gcry_strsource    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-global.o)
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_set_errno referenced in function _do_malloc  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-global.o)
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_set_errno    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-stdmem.o)
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_set_errno    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-secmem.o)
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_errno  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-module.o)
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_errno referenced in function _gpg_err_make_from_errno  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-global.o)
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_errno  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-sexp.o)
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_errno  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(md.o)
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_errno  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(primegen.o)
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___mingw_vsprintf referenced in function _sprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-sexp.o)
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___mingw_vsprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(ac.o)
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(primegen.o)
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror referenced in function _progress  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(dsa.o)
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(ecc.o)
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(random-fips.o)
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(mpicoder.o)
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(cipher.o)
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(pubkey.o)
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gpg_err_code_from_syserror   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(kdf.o)
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snprintf referenced in function __gcry_pk_get_keygrip    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(pubkey.o)
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _snprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(md.o)
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _snprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(ecc.o)
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _snprintf D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(rndw32.o)
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _getpagesize referenced in function _init_pool    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(libgcrypt_la-secmem.o)
Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gettimeofday referenced in function _x931_get_dt D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(random-fips.o)
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gettimeofday D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\libvlccore\libgcrypt.lib(random-csprng.o)
Error   34  error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\Release\libvlccore.dll
Error   89  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall UpdateDialog::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@UpdateDialog@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)    D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
Error   90  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall UpdateDialog::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@UpdateDialog@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)  D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
Error   91  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall UpdateDialog::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@UpdateDialog@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z) D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\lib_plugin\help.obj
Error   92  error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   D:\VidPlaya_offline\TryingToIncludeUpdateFacility\Vidplaya_Plugin_EmbeddedUpdate\vlcwin\Release\plugins\lib_plugin.dll

Any suggestions regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: You probably need to import an additional lib containing the missing symbol.

Comment: Even i am facing same issue.Any solutions?

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks for the replay. But how can i get to know the desired/needed .lib file?

Comment: I would guess there is documentation for the library concerned (libgcrypt?) and possibly a config.h that can be checked to make sure you haven't selected inappropriate options. Maybe you should rephrase your question and try to find users of the same library.

Comment: @RogerRowland I added #define UPDATE_CHECK in config.h.

Comment: @Myanju how? Often google will turn up details.  That decorated name is rather specific so I'll bet it finds similar questions to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically you have to find the library - .lib or .a (depending on the platform) file that has that symbol. Static libraries do not resolve their symbols until being linked into an executable or shared library, so you may have a static library that does not have all its symbols resolved. You can verify this using the tools mentioned lower in point 1 - when you dump the symbols the unresolved ones will have a `U` letter before them. And when you are linking them into your application the linker must resolve all the symbols, and if something is missing you get unresolved reference errors. You basically have two options:

1) Use a symbol dumping utility like `nm` (Linux and MinGW on Windows) or `dumpbin` (Visual Studio on Windows) and grep for the symbol (if you have a directory full of libraries you can make a script that does this for each file), and then when you know the correct library file link your code against it (again depends on platform `-l<library name>` switch for Linux and MinGW windows , add `#pragma comment(lib, "<library name>")` or specify the library through the property pages in Visual Studio.

2) If you have sources for all the libraries you can do a plain text search for the definition of the function and then linking against the library that has the source should do.

3) These issues may also appear even if you are already linking with the proper library but C and C++ code is being mixed. Libraries with C interface should have their header includes wrapped in an `extern "C"` block, so that the linker does not try to find a function with the C++ name when only a function with a C name is available. This is a common issue for beginners with FFmpeg and other big open source projects.

**UPDATE**

As for the original issue with `__mingw_vfprinf` — it is a bit weird that you are linking code that has been compiled with MinGW with Visual Studio, I'd say you'd be better of using MinGW for your project too, but as suggested in a [similar topic](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/undefined-reference-with-mingw-vfprintf-td17020.html) this could be cause by missing `libmingwex.a`. If you have the MinGW toolchain, find where the file is located, add that directory to linker search directories via Visual Studio property pages and add `libmingwex.a` as a linker input to your project either through the Visual Studio property pages or via the pragma mentioned above. If you don't have the MinGW toolchain then you should download it, but you need to get the right platform — however I guess since you got the library somewhere you know if it is 32bit or 64bit.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a sample screenshot of MinGW package manager showing which package contains the library:

[image: MinGW package manager showing libmingwex.a]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I downloaded mingw and installed. but i didn't find libmingwex.a in the installed directory. Should i have to select the specific package in the mingw installation manager?

Comment: Well, I looked into my MinGW installation and I have `libmingwex.a` under `C:\MinGW\lib` and `C:\MinGW\mingw32\lib`, it seems to be a part of the `mingw32-mingwrt` package. See the picture attached to the answer. Btw I did not see the updated question with the additional unresolved symbols, it could require more that just this lib.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis how can you tell from that post that he's mixing Visual Studio with mingw?

Comment: @jdlugosz well, the `LNK2019` is obviously from Visual Studio linker and if the library he is using has MinGW runtime linked in then most likely it was built with MinGW (except for the very small chance that someone used Visual Studio and linked in MinGW libraries which would make no sense, since all the standard input/output stuff is already in the Visual Studio runtime)

Comment: I didn't know if the other linkers used totally different formatting and error systems or not; it might be formatted to look like MS's on purpose.  Also, the LINK.EXE comes with the SDK platform without Visual Studio; since it's meant to be compatible with MSVCRT.dll and system libs, and you want the system headers from the SDK anyway, it might be sensible to use that linker in the toolchain.

Comment: @Myanju any progress with resolving the dependencies coming from MinGW?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis No it didn't help me. Actually i was compiling VLC 2.1.0 source code in that code software update feature was disabled so i defined define #UPDATE_CHECK in update.h file then i got all these errors. I'm new to this VC++ environment.

Comment: @Myanju you could have released this information faster. According to their wiki https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/ you should build VLC on Windows using MinGW, that is most likely why you get all the issues with Visual Studio. If you have time for chat I can try to help.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Sure. We can chat please let me know the suitable time.

Comment: @Myanju just start a chat on stackoverflow whenever you are online

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis i'm online now. Don't know how to chat, meanwhile i don't have much reputations.

Comment: @Myanju i created a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63771/vlc-build-on-windows - can you join it?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis The build is success but The application is failed to launch. 
program '[6036] VidPlayer.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741502 (0xc0000142).

Comment: @Myanju well then run it under the Visual Studio debugger to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis It's not even going to the WINAPI WinMain().

Comment: Since C0000142 means DLL Initialization Failed you can try to check what DLL's are needed by the exe with dependency walker and make sure they can all be loaded (they are in the DLL search path).

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Thanks for the suggestion. I loaded the .exe to dependency walker and then found these missing DLLs

API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL

DCOMP.DLL

GPSVC.DLL

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I don't think that, this will works for me. So i'm planning to implement update(as patches like in google chrome) feature newly. Any suggestions regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with other runtime library implementations leads me to suppose that various `printf` variations are implemented by calling a lower level `vprintf` form.  `fprintf` was put into thay .o file (why? Isn't that itself a RTL function?) and it needs that helper function.  From the name decorations, I expect that's to be found in a mingw system library.  I beleive that printf functions are in a supplimental library you need to link with, as it's enhanced over the ones in msvcrt.dll.

So, look for that.  Check your versions too, as maybe the lib was built against a different version than you're using now and those details have changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i link the msvcrt.dll to my project?

Comment: You are already.  I think you should review the basics of mingw's compile/link architecture and its relationship to the windows system32 library (msvcrt).